# php echo to Javascript produces over-nested json

Tags: javascript, php

I'm obviously over-processing the rows being returned from my query, but I don't really understand PHP resources and row counts and arrays.

This is my database call:

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $rows[] = array($r);
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);            
};
```

This is what I'm getting back in my Javascript:

```
Object {data: Array[23], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
    data: Array[23]
        0:Array[1] <-- superfluous
            0: Object
                Name: "foo"
                Order: "0"
                uID: "1"
        1:Array[1] <-- superfluous
            0: Object
                Name: "bar"
                Order: "1"
                uID: "2"
        ...
```

There's a superfluous array layer in there. It should look like this:

```
Object {data: Array[23], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
    data: Array[23]
        0:Object
            Name: "foo"
            Order: "0"
            uID: "1"
        1: Object
            Name: "bar"
            Order: "1"
            uID: "2"
        ...
```

I'm tempted to remove the **rows = array()** but I don't know how. I don't get how to turn my db rows into an array properly.

Comment: $rows[] = (array)$r;

Comment: The problem is at `$rows[] = array($r);` make this like `$rows[] = $r`

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all correct

```
 $rows[] =  $r;
```

And then in javascript use JSON.parse

```
JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: Thank you. The first fix worked. I'm not sure what the second fix is for. Surely the $http call is expecting and receiving JSON as the response. I mean ... it works without that fix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at `$rows[] = array($r);`

Make a little change do this like: `$rows[] = $r`, I think after that you will get the array not object. You can encode the array with the additional `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` so that your array make an object json.

Example after normal `json_encode`:

```
Object {data: Array[23], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
    data: Array[23]
        0:Array[3]
            Name: "foo"
            Order: "0"
            uID: "1"
        1: Array[3]
            Name: "bar"
            Order: "1"
            uID: "2"
        ...
```